# Bootstrap matching table width with container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I match my table's width with its container? Without any css changes, my table overflows and is much wider than its container.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tet8L/
[image: Table is overflowing out of container.]

When I mess around with setting the width to auto, I get a table that fills only part of the container.

```
.table {
  width: auto; (or fixed or none)
}
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DDnSL/
[image: Table width is too short.]

Is there a way to get my table to automatically fill the entire container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html you have

```
<div class="starter-template">
     <div class="container">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Change this to

```
<div class="starter-template">
     <div class="container-fluid">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tet8L/3/)

**UPDATE:**

Forget what I just wrote, just get rid of the `.container` div, because you already have a `.container` div in your code. I just had a look at the Bootstrap docs and they say,

> containers are not nestable by default

[Bootstrap Docs (containers)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

```
<div class="starter-template">
     <div>
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tet8L/4/)