# Bootstrap table overflows parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `HTML`

```
<div class="page-content container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="#">Add Exercise</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <caption>Exercises</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Technique</th>
                    <th>Sub Technique</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Accents</th>
                    <th>Min Persons</th>
                    <th>Max Persons</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Lorem</td>
                    <td>Ipsum</td>
                    <td>Dolor</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</td>
                    <td>sit</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem i'm having is that the `table` overflows the `.row` parent. I've tried several thing, searched on google and found some answers but no solutions (at least not for me).

I tried [this](http://www.bootply.com/9njmoY2CmS) but then all columns are equal width and I don't want that.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897377/making-wide-table-fit-bootstrap-container), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750661/bootstrap-matching-table-width-with-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809157/table-wider-than-bootstrap-column-container) but nothing does the trick for me.

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njejLL83/) so you can see what I mean. What I want is to fit all the content inside the `.container` with the red border.

EDIT:

Problem appears to be only occuring in chrome.

Expected Output:[image: Expected Output]

Comment: in which resolution / browser last 2 cols coming out, can u provide screenshot of expected output?

Comment: For me it was simply a case of the container not being wide enough... I just manually set a wider size for the container. One can also use `.fluid-container` but that might end up being too wide.

Answer (score 0):

By default table-layout is set to auto. You need to set it to fixed so that it can take the width:

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[solved fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/njejLL83/1/)

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't want equal width columns

Answer (score 0):

Using `table-layout:fixed` will make the columns equals of equal width and wont break your `max-width:100%` by overflowing.

But given the fact that you have a 'long-content column', you might give that column a class name and set a `max-width` value for that class.

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't want equal width columns.